# Putting textfile into Listbox using streamreader

Tags: c#, streamreader

I was wondering how i can make the program read a text file and put the contents in the listbox using streamreader?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

 }         (StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader("C:\Users\tommy\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication9\WindowsFormsApplication9\bin\Debug\transactions.txt"))
{
    while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(stRead.ReadLine());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Be aware of the @ at the beginning of the file path. Using backslash in a string literal must be escaped if @ not used.

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\tommy\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication9\WindowsFormsApplication9\bin\Debug\transactions.txt"));
```

[Using StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
        // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file. 
        // The using statement also closes the StreamReader. 
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt")) 
        {
            string line;
            // Read and display lines from the file until the end of  
            // the file is reached. 
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You already post a answer of this question. Please mearge your code with previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

An much easier way is to use [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("yourFile");
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.file.readalllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also,

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines( @"yourFile" );

lines.ForEach( x => Listbox1.Items.Add( x ) );
```